# Count characters in H1 tag

Tags: jquery, count, character

I need to count the number of characters rendered in an H1 tag. Is there any way to do this. I know there are a lot of character counters but they seem to be built for inputs/textareas. Many thanks in advance.

C

Comment: Do you want to count only characters rendered to the screen or all characters (including markup)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
alert("Text length: "+$("h1").text().length);
```

Not counting whitespace:

```
alert("Text length: "+$("h1").text().replace(" ", "").length);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished by passing a function into the `.text()` method in jQuery.

```
$("h1").text(function(index, text){
    alert(text.length);
});
```

*note*, this will run for every `<h1/>` on your page.

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/8v9MB/).**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var length = $("h1").html().length;
alert(length);
```

Answer (score 0):

if this tag has a class (in this case h1class) then you might be able to use something like:

```
alert($(".h1class").text().length);
```

you could also use it directly but that might get you in trouble if there are more than one h1 tag

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your question right, so forgive me if i give you a wrong answer, but i think what you want to do is get the text out of the tag first

```
$('h1').text().length
```

or if you want to count the inside tag as well you can do

```
$('h1').html().toString().length
```

Answer (score 0):

Made what you want with

```
<h1>oi oi oi </h1>
```

and

```
console.log($('h1').contents()[0].length);
```

If you're H1 had an ID it would probably be better